# Gram matrix using VexCL

Tags: c++, opencl

I have a pretty large data (does not fit into a GPU memory) containing many vectors where each vector is several MBs.
I'd like to calculate, using multiple GPU devices, the Gram matrix using a gaussian kernel.

In other words, for every pair of vectors x,y, I need to calculate the norm of x-y. So if I have N vectors, I have (N^2+N)/2 such pairs. I don't care about saving space or time by taking advantage of the symmetry, it can do the whole N^2.

How can I do it with [VexCL](https://github.com/ddemidov/vexcl)? I know its the only library supporting multiple GPUs, and I did pretty much doing it effectively with plain OpenCL with no success so far.

Please note that the dataset won't even fit the machine's RAM, I'm reading blocks of vectors from a memory mapped file.

Thanks much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will obviously need to split your vectors into groups of, say, `m`, load the groups one by one (or, rather, two by two) onto your GPUs and do the computations. Here is a complete program that does the computation (as I understood it) for the two currently loaded chunks:

```
#include <vexcl/vexcl.hpp>

int main() {
    const size_t n = 1024; // Each vector size.
    const size_t m = 4;    // Number of vectors in a chunk.

    vex::Context ctx( vex::Filter::Count(1) );

    // The input vectors...
    vex::vector<double> chunk1(ctx, m * n);
    vex::vector<double> chunk2(ctx, m * n);

    // ... with some data.
    chunk1 = vex::element_index();
    chunk2 = vex::element_index();

    vex::vector<double> gram(ctx, m * m); // The current chunk of Gram matrix to fill.

    /*
     * chunk1 and chunk2 both have dimensions [m][n].
     * We want to take each of chunk2 m rows, subtract those from each of
     * chunk1 rows, and reduce the result along the dimension n.
     *
     * In order to do this, we create two virtual 3D matrices (x and y below,
     * those are just expressions and are never instantiated) sized [m][m][n],
     * where
     *
     *     x[i][j][k] = chunk1[i][k] for each j, and
     *     y[i][j][k] = chunk2[j][k] for each i.
     *
     * Then what we need to compute is
     *
     *     gram[i][j] = sum_k( (x[i][j][k] - y[i][j][k])^2 );
     *
     * Here it goes:
     */
    using vex::extents;

    auto x = vex::reshape(chunk1, extents[m][m][n], extents[0][2]);
    auto y = vex::reshape(chunk2, extents[m][m][n], extents[1][2]);

    // The single OpenCL kernel is generated and launched here:
    gram = vex::reduce<vex::SUM>(
            extents[m][m][n],     // The dimensions of the expression to reduce.
            pow(x - y, 2.0),      // The expression to reduce.
            2                     // The dimension to reduce along.
            );

    // Copy the result to host, spread it across your complete gram matrix.
    // I am lazy though, so let's just dump it to std::cout:
    std::cout << gram << std::endl;
}
```

I suggest you load `chunk1` once, then in sequence load all `chunk2` variants and do the computations, then load next `chunk1`, etc. etc. Note that slicing, reshaping, and multidimensional reduction operations are only supported for a context with a single compute device in it. So what is left is how to spread the computations across all of your compute devices. The easiest way to do this is probably to create single VexCL context that would grab all available GPUs, and then create vectors of command queues out of it:

```
vex::Context ctx( vex::Filter::Any );

std::vector<std::vector<vex::command_queue>> q;
for(size_t d = 0; d < ctx.size(); ++d)
    q.push_back({ctx.queue(d)});


//...

// In a std::thread perhaps:
chunk1(q[d], m * n);
chunk2(q[d], m * n);
// ...
```

I hope this is enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! 
Let me clarify the algorithm: K(n,k)=sum((x[n]-x[k])^2) where x[n],x[k] are vectors of length M and we have N such vectors, so K is NxN (but symmetric so only (N^2+N)/2 elements). Question please: is it possible to make operations in non-blocking mode? Also I didn't get why 2 chunks, we have only 1 list of vectors. Maybe for intermediate?

Comment: I've edited the answer to take the actual norm into account. Regarding the non-blocking mode: you could create two command queues per device, create two pairs of chunks, and load one pair while the other pair is being processed. Associating each pair of vectors with its own command queue would be enough to achieve this.

Comment: Regarding two chunks: you need to pair each vector with each other vector, right? But if you have only one chunk, then you can pair every vector in that chunk only with vectors from the same chunk.

Comment: Yes, they're needed to be compared to the same chunk. An easy way to simplifay Gram is to take a linear kernel, in which K=A*(A^T). If you give an efficient way to compute A*(A^T) when A is a NxM matrix, you completely solved the Gram problem.

Comment: Does that mean that you want your Gram matrix to be block-diagonal? Because that's what you would get from a single chunk approach.

Comment: It's not block diagonal, only symmetric.

Comment: An expression to transpose an NxM matrix A is `reshape(A, extents[M][N], [1][0])`. For the matrix multiplication see [this comment](https://github.com/ddemidov/vexcl/issues/31#issuecomment-28979255). But you'll probably want to use a vendor-specific BLAS implementation to make it as efficient as possible.

Comment: Then you will need two chunks to traverse both rows and columns of your Gram matrix.

Comment: You wrote: gram[i][j] = sum_k( (x[i][j][k] - y[i][j][k])^2 ) but it should be gram[i][j] = sum_k( (x[i][k] - x[j][k])^2 )

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47185/discussion-between-ddemidov-and-troy-mcclure)